# I want to create composite band image through batch processing using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, python-script-tool, for-loop, data-management

I have multiple Sentinel 2a raster images in separated folders at same location, which means every image is in separate folder. Now I want to create composite band of each raster. I have written a code and its given an error, its says

File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\genericpath.py", line 91, in _splitext
sepIndex = p.rfind(sep)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'

How do I specify arguments in composite band?

Here is the code

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.workspace = r"L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image\T44QPJ_20200405"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

input_raster = arcpy.ListRasters()
outputDir = r"L:\Arcpy\Data\Layer_stack"
print(input_raster)

blue = r"L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image\T44QPJ_20200405_B02_10m.jp2"
green = r"L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B03_10m.jp2"
red = r"L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B04_10m.jp2"
nir = r"L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B08_10m.jp2"
swir_1 = r"L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B011_20m.jp2"
swir_2 = r"L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B012_20m.jp2"

# the first part of the file name before extension (if present) then add *.img
output = os.path.join(outputDir,os.path.splitext(input_raster)[0].split('_')[0] + '.img')
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(";".join([blue,green,red,nir,swir_1,swir_2]), output)
```

I am stuck in CompositeBands_managemnet tool. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be like this

```
import arcpy, os

#Define the workspace that contains all of the folders with the Sentinel Imagery
arcpy.env.workspace = "L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image"

#Specify where you would like the output to go
output = "L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Layer_stack"

# List of all workspace perviously defind the workspace.
folders = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()

for folder in folders:
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    images = arcpy.ListRasters("*.jp2")# Filter all bands in the folder.
    print "images: "+str(images)
    name = os.path.join(output, images[1].split("_")[0] + ".img")
    arcpy.CompositeBands_management(images, name)
print(images)
print "Finished"
```

Answer (score 1):

You were passing [raster objects](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm) to a function that does not want them. Possible inputs to Composite bands are:

> Mosaic Dataset ; Mosaic Layer ; Raster Dataset ; Raster Layer

Try something like:

```
import arcpy

b02 = r"D:\Sentinel2\202006\S2A_MSIL2A_20200613T103031_N0214_R108_T33VVJ_20200613T120604.SAFE\GRANULE\L2A_T33VVJ_A025988_20200613T103028\IMG_DATA\R10m\T33VVJ_20200613T103031_B02_10m.jp2"
b11 = r"D:\Sentinel2\202006\S2A_MSIL2A_20200613T103031_N0214_R108_T33VVJ_20200613T120604.SAFE\GRANULE\L2A_T33VVJ_A025988_20200613T103028\IMG_DATA\R20m\T33VVJ_20200613T103031_B11_20m.jp2"
b12 = r"D:\Sentinel2\202006\S2A_MSIL2A_20200613T103031_N0214_R108_T33VVJ_20200613T120604.SAFE\GRANULE\L2A_T33VVJ_A025988_20200613T103028\IMG_DATA\R20m\T33VVJ_20200613T103031_B12_20m.jp2"

arcpy.CompositeBands_management(in_rasters=";".join([b02,b11,b12]), out_raster=r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\123out.tif")
```

Comment: I have done changes in the code as you say, but this time I get this error raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000271: Cannot open the input datasets
Failed to execute (CompositeBands). On above code I made the changes also

Comment: Your rasters are directly in the `Satellite_image` folder (not in a subfolder to it)? The for loop doesnt do anything relevant as of now. In fact, if `input_raster` is an empty list then I belive composite bands will fail because `blue green red etc` will then be nothing. Try removing the foor loop (only this line: `for data in input_raster:`) and see if composite bands work then.

Comment: I made changes as you say this time error occurred in split text. File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\genericpath.py", line 91, in _splitext
    sepIndex = p.rfind(sep)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Comment: What is the actual name you want as output? It might be easier to extract it from any of the bands path

Comment: I want the Tile name means like T44QPJ.

Comment: You could do `blue.split('\\')[-1].split('_')[0]`. Your use of \\ complicates things a bit, for example you cant use os.path.basename etc. You could use r and \ as in my answer if you want

Comment: This time error came in Composite Band, It gives ExecuteError: ERROR 000271: Cannot open the input datasets
Failed to execute (CompositeBands).

Comment: Anyone have solution of this code?

Comment: I am trying every possible way that you suggested, but it is not running.